# How to perform an elementwise addition in an Eigen sparse matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have the following code where AMAT is currrently a dense matrix. However most of the elements are zero such that essentially it is a sparse matrix. I understand block operations are not supported in Eigen sparse matrix. Wondering how I can rewrite this code if I replace AMAT as a sparse matrix. BMAT is a 9x9 dense matrix and every 3x3 block of BMAT is added to specific blocks in AMAT. BMAT is calculated outside this loop.

```
    for(j=0;j<5000;j++) {

      id1 = ids(0,j);
      id2 = ids(1,j);
      id3 = ids(2,j);

      AMAT.block<3,3>(id1*3,id1*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id1*3,id1*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(0,0);
      AMAT.block<3,3>(id1*3,id2*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id1*3,id2*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(0,3);
      AMAT.block<3,3>(id1*3,id3*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id1*3,id3*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(0,6);

      AMAT.block<3,3>(id2*3,id1*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id2*3,id1*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(3,0);
      AMAT.block<3,3>(id2*3,id2*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id2*3,id2*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(3,3);
      AMAT.block<3,3>(id2*3,id3*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id2*3,id3*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(3,6);

      AMAT.block<3,3>(id3*3,id1*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id3*3,id1*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(6,0);
      AMAT.block<3,3>(id3*3,id2*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id3*3,id2*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(6,3);
      AMAT.block<3,3>(id3*3,id3*3) = AMAT.block<3,3>(id3*3,id3*3) + BMAT.block<3,3>(6,6);

   }
```

Comment: Do you always/only access `AMAT` in 3x3 blocks? Is it empty before your loop? What operations do you do do with it afterwards?

Comment: Yes. AMAT is empty before the loop begins to fill it.It is filled in as 3x3 blocks. Once the loop is complete I am solving the linear system Ax=b where A is AMAT

Comment: Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this request

Comment: You can fill try defining `AMAT` as `SparseMatrix<Array33f>` -- then a "3x3 block" can simply be accessed using `AMAT.coeffRef(idX,idY) += BMAT.block<3,3>(3*X, 3*Y);` -- this won't allow using `AMAT` to solve linear equations, though. Alternatively you could write a custom iterator over your `ids` matrix, which gives 81 index pairs and the corresponding element of `BMAT` for each row in `ids` and pass that to `setFromTriplets`. (Or a combination of both)

Comment: Thank you chtz. Looking at your second recommendation, if I convert each 3x3 block to a triplet then I can construct AMAT from these triplets correct? Is there a method to represent a dense matrix as a trplet without looping over the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work (untested, and I don't know the actual types of your matrices). The idea is to write a custom iterator which provides the indices and values of every entry of `AMAT` and pass that to `setFromTriplets` (duplicate entries will be summed together). This will iterate twice through your index list, but unfortunately not exploit the block structure of `AMAT`. But it will execute in O(nnz) time.

```
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>

struct AMAT_constructor {
  struct AMAT_iterator {
    bool operator==(AMAT_iterator const& other) const {
      return j == other.j && k == other.k;
    }

    bool operator!=(AMAT_iterator const& other) const {
      return !(*this == other);
    }

    Eigen::Index operator-(AMAT_iterator const& other) const {
      return (j - other.j) * 81 + k - other.k;
    }

    AMAT_iterator const* operator->() const { return this; }
    AMAT_iterator const& operator*() const { return *this; }
    float value() const { return BMAT(k); }
    Eigen::Index row() const { return ids((k / 3) % 3, j) * 3 + k % 3; }

    Eigen::Index col() const { return ids(k / 27, j) * 3 + (k / 9) % 3; }

    AMAT_iterator& operator++() {
      if (++k == 81) {
        k = 0;
        ++j;
      }
      return *this;
    }

    Eigen::Index j, k;
    Eigen::Matrix3Xi const& ids;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 9, 9> const& BMAT;
  };

  Eigen::Matrix3Xi const& ids;
  Eigen::Matrix<float, 9, 9> const& BMAT;

  AMAT_iterator begin() const { return AMAT_iterator{0, 0, ids, BMAT}; }
  AMAT_iterator end() const { return AMAT_iterator{ids.cols(), 0, ids, BMAT}; }
};

// use it like this:
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> foo(Eigen::Matrix3Xi const& ids,
                               Eigen::Matrix<float, 9, 9> const& BMAT,
                               Eigen::Index sizeA) {

  Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> AMAT(sizeA, sizeA);
  AMAT_constructor Ac{ids, BMAT};
  AMAT.setFromTriplets(Ac.begin(), Ac.end());

  return AMAT;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can expand on this. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this tutorial in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html block-operations are possible. But you need to know the columns and rows at compile-time.

Comment: Yes. block operations are possible for dense matrices which is what I have now. I would like to know how to do the same for sparse matrix, since in the above example AMAT is sparse with less than 1% of non zero entries

Comment: There are two different syntaxes for block operations: `foo.block<3,3>(r, c)` if size known statically and `foo.block(r,c,3,3)` which will work in any case.